# Using gets.chomp to pass list of strings as arguments

Tags: ruby, arrays, arguments

I have a hash:

```
@menu = { "pizza" =>  10, "burger" => 2, "kebab" => 5 }
```

and an `order` method like this:

```
def order *food, total
  running_total = self.menu.values_at(*food)
  cash = running_total.inject(0) {|sum, num| sum + num}
  if total == cash
    send_text
    puts 'Text has been sent' 
  else
    fail 'Not enough cash'
  end
end
```

I'm trying to ask the customer for order using `gets.chomp`. How would I use the responses from the user? `gets.chomp` seems to chuck the strings into an array, which is then passed as `nil` to the method.

This is what I have so far:

```
puts 'Please place order'
placed_order = gets.chomp.split(' ')
puts 'Payment?'
total = gets.chomp.to_i
order(placed_order, total)
```

How would I pass the total as an argument as well?

Comment: How is `@menu` relevant to your question?

Comment: @sawa I guess he meant to say "I have a \@menu hash with an attr_reader".

Comment: yeah sorry, @menu is a hash that is initialized with the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... gets.chomp seems to chuck the strings into an array"

> the split method does this

Based on the way you've defined `order` you either need to do
`order(*placed_order, total)`
or redefine the `order` signature to `def order food, total` (a name that conveys that food expects an array, such as foods, might be "in order")

Slightly off-topic, you can shorten the order method as follows:

```
def order *food, total
   cash = menu.values_at(*food).inject(&:+)
   #...
```

Also, shouldn't "total" and "cash" be swapped (total == how much money you want; cash == how much they've given you)?

Comment: hi this worked perfectly, I was wondering if you know how I can ignore the comma's with gets.chomp? just so it flows when inputting an order

Comment: This assumes your input is space separated, if you want it comma separated or seperated with commas and optional spaces behind them, you could split the result on `/,\s*/` instead.

Comment: @Munded If you're happy with the answer, please upvote it or mark it as accepted or both. Thanks.

Comment: oh and the commas I'm referring to are those when inputting my order, as instead of typing "Burger Burger" I can type "Burger, Burger" without it failing